# What is wrong with the following argument?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Say we have a set $X$ and an equivalence relation $C$ on $X$. Why do we need reflexivity?

Let $x,y \in X$ with $xCy $. By symmetry we obtain $yCx$.

Applying now transitivity, we have $xCx$.

So, we have reflexivity from symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: Does such a $y$ exist for all $x$?

Comment: @user2520938: Does this mean that reflexivity only deals with equivalence classes containing a single element? Without reflexivity those would not be equivalence classes at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to assume there exists, $xCy$. Indeed it's not necessarily true. Think about an extreme cases that $X\neq \emptyset$ and define a relation $C$ on $X$ such that $C$ contains nothing, that is, no element of $X$ is in the relation, then clearly the relation is symmetry and transitive, but not reflexive.

Comment: This is not true! There is a logical flaw in it. Any relation on the empty set is both symmetric, transitive AND reflexive: It DOES hold that for all $x\in\emptyset$ we have $xCx$. Just check all the possible $x$'s ... ;)

Comment: @String I think I specified that $X\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. I read $X=\emptyset$. The point seems to be, that if any element of $X$ is isolated (i.e. not equivalent to any other), then reflexivity is needed in order to make all elements of $X$ belong to an equivalence class.

Comment: @String Yes, you are right.